# How to perform division over two SELECT queries?

Tags: sql

I have two query results that produce numbers. I am wondering how I can combine the two queries into one division operation.

I have my query as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Games WHERE Title = "Zelda" - This gets me my numerator
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Games - This is my denominator.
```

I want to write a query that is the result set of the numerator / denominator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With conditional `sum`:

```
select sum(case when Title = 'Zelda' then 1 else 0) / count(*) as result from Games
```

The above code will do integer division.  
 
If you need more precision:

```
select 1.0 * sum(case when Title = 'Zelda' then 1 else 0) / count(*) as result from Games
```

Also **if your rdbms allows it** you can do this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Games WHERE Title = "Zelda") /(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Games)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` inside `FORM`:

```
SELECT CAST(T1.N AS float)/T2.D FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS N FROM Games WHERE Title = "Zelda") T1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS D FROM Games) T2
```

Each query of yours could be treated as a table (with one result variable), just give them names using `AS` and then create outer query that selects the arithmetic operation you want. (Casting the result to float to get the ratio).

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT AVG( (Title = 'Zelda)::int) 
FROM Games;
```

I think this is the simplest query that does what you want (assuming that `Title` is never `NULL`.